# Implementing Google Analytics via Tag Manager - does it effect Google Analytics opt out browser plugin?

Tags: google, google-analytics, browsers, google-tag-manager, data

Im about to add Google Analytics to a new site, im going to do this via the Tag Manager, If i implement Google Analytics via the Tag manager as opposed to the Google Analytics tracking code, will users who have the [Google Analytics opt](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout) out plugin installed in their browser still be excluded from the data ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they will be excluded. Website visitors have the ability to prevent their data to be used.

I also tried to do that via Tag Manager too, but it doesn't work.